# What happens to a process handle once the process was ended?

Tags: windows, winapi, process, handle

if I have a handle to some windows process which has stopped (killed or just ended):

1. Will the handle (or better the memory behind it) be re-used for another process?
2. Or will GetExitCodeProcess() for example get the correct result forever from now on?

If 1. is true: How "long" would GetExitCodeProcess() work?
If 2. is true: Wouldn't that mean that I can bring down the OS with starting/killing new processes, since I create more and more handles (and the OS reserves memory for them)?

I'm a bit confused about the concept of handles.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Very interesting. I bet, GetExitCodeProcess would work until parent (calling) process exit. Don't have time to test it right now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The handle indirectly points to an kernel object. As long as there are open handles, the object will be kept alive.

> Will the handle (or better the memory behind it) be re-used for another process?

The numeric value of the handle (or however it is implemented) might get reused, but that doesn't mean it'll always point to the same thing. Just like process IDs.

> Or will GetExitCodeProcess() for example get the correct result forever from now on?

No. When all handles to the process are closed, the process object is freed (along with its exit code). Note that running process holds an implicit handle to itself. You can hold an open handle, though, as long as you need it.

> If 2. is true: Wouldn't that mean that I can bring down the OS with starting/killing new processes, since I create more and more handles (and the OS reserves memory for them)?

There are many ways to starve the system. It will either start heavily swapping or just fail to spawn a new process at some point.

Comment: Thank you. For clarification: If I call CreateProcess(),  which returns a handle in the PROCESS_INFORMATION struct, GetExitCodeProcess() would work until I close this (and any other) handle?

Comment: @beuteluchs: Yes, as long as there is at least one open handle to that process, querying will work.

Comment: Thank you, helped me a lot. Felt a bit lost on MSDN.

Comment: Once you reach "the limit", which is currently 16M handles, the operating system will simply make every call that creates another handle fail with `ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES` (0x5aa). 16M handles consume 192MB of memory on a 64bit system (128MB on a 32bit system). If you can bring a system down by allocating 192MB, the system has an entirely different problem. Note that some specific handles which require more resources have additional hardcoded limits in the lower thousands.

Comment: @Damon: Creating a process involves a lot more than just allocating a handle, though. I'd say 16M processes have a potential of bringing the system to at least a crawl. ;)

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: Well yes, a process would inevitably have at least a PEB structure which occupies a full nonshareable memory page (even if the process had no executable code at all). Let's not even think of the CPU overhead of spawning 16M processes... :-)  I was more referring to the handles as such. But then again you can always `for(;;)malloc(1024*1024)` to bog down the system. There is little one can do to prevent users from burning resources on purpose.

Comment: Good answer; one slight clarification, just be be on the safe side: the handle value won't get reused within a process until that process closes it. (Note that pids, by contrast, can be recycled immediately.)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

`GetExitCodeProcess` works until you call `CloseHandle`, after what the process object will be released and may be reused.

Long answer:
See Cat Plus Plus's answer.