# CloseHandle(process) returns ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE on ended process but keeps handle

Tags: process, handle

I have an issue with handles which I can't explain.

Situation:
An application/process

1. starts itself again (with different parameters) using `CreateProcess` calling its EXE-file
2. waits until this new instance is finished using `WaitForSingleObject`
3. Once `WaitForSingleObject` return 0 I get the exitcode using `GetExitCodeProcess`
4. I close the handle to the ended proccess using `CloseHandle`

Every call returns success except the `CloseHandle`which returns `false` and `GetLastError`returns 6 (=ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE).

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531620/what-happens-to-a-process-handle-once-the-process-was-ended) the the process stays valid until the last handle closes. Which doesn't seem true for me.

The issue I have is according to the ProcessExplorer/Taskmanager each time I call `CreateProcess` the handle count of the proccess increases by 2. Over time the handlecount is so high that the whole Windows starts to act weird and freeze...

The bottom part of ProcExp lists one handle to a non-existing-process and one to a non-existing-thread for each call..

Thanks for your input.

PS: The application is written in PowerBuilder using external function calls to the kernel32.dll. The simplified code looks like this:

```
// Declaration of CloseHandle as local external function
Function boolean CloseHandle (ulong hObject) Library "KERNEL32.DLL"
....
// Start another process
CreateProcess (lul_null, "~"" + as_command + "~" " + as_arguments, lul_null, lul_null, TRUE, 32, lul_null, ls_null, lstr_startupinfo, lstr_proc) 

// Just for test
gf_log_into_file("HANDLE="+string(lstr_proc.ul_process))
WaitForInputIdle(lstr_proc.ul_process, al_millisecs)

// Wait until the process closes
do
    do while Yield()
    loop            
    lul_rc = WaitForSingleObject (lstr_proc.ul_process, al_millisecs)
loop while lul_rc = WAIT_TIMEOUT

// get exit code
GetExitCodeProcess(lstr_proc.ul_process, ref al_ret)
// this one still returns TRUE!!

gf_log_into_file("HANDLE="+string(lstr_proc.ul_process))

// closehandle returns FALSE 2 times
if NOT CloseHandle(lstr_proc.ul_thread) then lul_rc = GetLastError()
// lul_rc = 6
if NOT CloseHandle(lstr_proc.ul_process) then lul_rc = GetLastError()
// lul_rc = 6 which means ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE. But why?? For GetExitCodeProcess(..) one line above the handle was still OK

gf_log_into_file("HANDLE="+string(lstr_proc.ul_process))
```

Comment: Process Explorer and Task Manager are both correct.  `CreateProcess()` does return 2 `HANDLE`s - one for the new process, and one for the process's main thread.  You have to close both handles when you are done using them.  Sounds like something is killing your spawned process prematurely before you can close those handles.  But without seeing your actual code, it is hard to diagnose this problem.

Comment: Thanks, I added the code above. What really puzzeling is that for GetExitCodeProcess() the handle is fine, but not for CloseHandle... I've also tried to call CloseHandle() with all 4 values in the PROCESS_INFORMATION struc that CreateProcess returns. For all 4 CloseHandle() returns FALSE with error=6

Comment: `PROCESS_INFORMATION` only has two `HANDLE` fields, both of which must be passed to `CloseHandle()`. The other two fields are `DWORD` for the process ID and thread ID, which are not handles.

Comment: I am not familiar with PowerBuilder. How does `lul_rc` get assigned the return value of `WaitForSingleObject()`? You are explicitly assigning `lul_rc` when calling `GetLastError()`. Shouldn't you be doing the same for `WaitForSingleObject()`?

Comment: Sorry, was a typo in the source. I don't think it has to do anything with powerbuilder as the code is straight forward. Its frustrating.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is if `GetExitCodeProcess()` or  `al_ret` is declared wrong, causing memory corruption when `GetExitCodeProcess()` is called, and it *happens* to be corrupting the `lstr_proc.ul_process` value. Did you verify that `lstr_proc` and `ul_process` are the same values before and after calling `GetExitCodeProcess()`? Did you try removing `GetExitCodeProcess()` as a test?

Comment: Done. I removed the `GetExitCodeProcess()` and logged the handle just after the `CreateProcess` and just after and before the `CloseHandle()`. In addition I added two `CloseHandle()` calls. One for the Thread and one for the process. Handle is the same on all logs. So no problem here. But both `CloseHandle()` return false with error=ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE

Comment: You say you added *two* more calls to `CloseHandle()`, but you only needed *one* - to close the thread handle. You are already closing the process handle. There is nothing else to close. What are you actually closing now? Please show your code. Since you claim the handles are not changing value, the only remaining factor is `CloseHandle()` itself. Maybe it is declared wrong and thus not being called correctly? Can you pause your code before `CloseHandle()` and then look at the open handles in Process Explorer to make sure they are accurate?

Comment: Thx for your help man. I changed the code as it is right now. the gf_log_into_file(...) reports the same handle all the time. So it doesn't get lost somehow. In addition I added the declaration of `CloseHandle()`. ulong is the right type for a handle in PB. I use the same for all other methods as well (i.e.`GetExitCodeProcess()`).

Comment: I'm out of ideas then, sorry.

Comment: @Soko on which exact platform did you experience that problem?  I've got a similar behaviour with pipe handles but can reproduce it only on Windows Server 2012; the same code runs fine on Windows 7.

Comment: @AlexanderDunaev: I (still) use Windows XP 64-bit on that VM